# How to tell a NavLink in a component with multiple routers to change the route of only in one of them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-router-dom

Im working on a **react** project with **react-router-dom**.

my root `App` component is a `<Router>` wrapping a `<Switch>`, that has 2 `<Routes>`:

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <Route to="/" component={Intro}>
      <Route to="/dashboard/home" component={Dashboard}>
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

**Dashboard Component** has **its own inner** `<Router>`.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
   render(){
      <div>
         <Menu>
         <Router>
            <Switch>
               <Route to="/dashboard/home">
               <Route to="/dashboard/about">
               <Route to="/dashboard/contact">
            </Switch>
         <Router>
      </div>

   }
}
```

`<Menu>` has a `<NavLink>` to each of the routes, **and has an extra** `<NavLink>` that suppose to take you back to the **Intro component/page**.

`<Intro>`is not part of the dashboard's view. it's a separate page.

**My Problem:**

my **"Back to Intro"** link,  `<NavLink to="/">`, changes the route inside the Dashboard Router, **but I need it to change the route of the outer router.**

what is the right way of arranging  my routers in order to have a path back to the outer one ?

This is the project screen navigation concept:

```
Intro <---> Dashboard --> different content
```